# How do I initialize my json response in another class that depends on a search input in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

this is my first question here on stackoverflow.

I'm working on my first real app after attending a few CS classes at University and some courses on Udemy. So I'm lacking a lot of software engineering knowledge.

My goal: I want to build a search for stocks by using an external API endpoint. For that, I have created 4 dart files to handle the searchscreen with inputs (My UI), networking, parsing, and basically returning the data.

My NetworkAPI class to handle all sorts of network requests looks like this. I'm trying to use the jsonDecode already here and returning that. This class waits for an URL that will be put together in another class (financeData):

```
class NetworkAPI {
  final String url;
  NetworkAPI(this.url);

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      return jsonDecode(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

This is basically the Json I want to parse. If I understood the theory correctly it's a map with a list of objects.

```
          {
                "bestMatches": [
                    {
                        "1. symbol": "TESO",
                        "2. name": "Tesco Corporation USA",
                        "3. type": "Equity",
                        "4. region": "United States",
                        "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
                        "6. marketClose": "16:00",
                        "7. timezone": "UTC-04",
                        "8. currency": "USD",
                        "9. matchScore": "0.8889"
                    }
                    {....}
                ]
            }
```

To parse this, I saw some really good explanations here on stack overflow. I'm basically trying to retrieve the information I'm interested in.

```
class SearchOutput {

  final List<BestMatch> bestMatches;
  SearchOutput({this.bestMatches});

  factory SearchOutput.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){

   var list = parsedJson['bestMatches'] as List;
   print(list.runtimeType);

   List<BestMatch> searchResultList = list.map((i) => BestMatch.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return SearchOutput(
        bestMatches: searchResultList,
    );
  }

}

class BestMatch {
  String symbol;
  String name;
  String type;
  String region;
  String currency;

  BestMatch({
    this.symbol,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.region,
    this.currency,
  });

  factory BestMatch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return BestMatch(
      symbol: parsedJson["1. symbol"],
      name: parsedJson["2. name"],
      type: parsedJson["3. type"],
      region: parsedJson["4. region"],
      currency: parsedJson["8. currency"],
    );
  }
}
```

Now I created a class with a method that should return all my data and format it into a list. The URL still needs an searchInput, which will be handed over from a TextField Widget in the UI.

```
const apiKey = 'demo';
const alphaVantageSearchUrl =
    'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH';

class FinanceData {

  Future<dynamic> getSearchData(String searchInput) async {
    var url = '$alphaVantageSearchUrl&keywords=$searchInput&apikey=$apiKey';
    NetworkAPI networkAPI = NetworkAPI(url);
    var searchData = await networkAPI.getData();
    SearchOutput searchOutput = new SearchOutput.fromJson(searchData);
    return searchOutput;
  }
}
```

Testing with some print statements seems to fullfill my goal of being able to access the data. For example printing out the name of the second object out of my response.

```
 print(searchOutput.bestMatches[1].name);
```

The last file is my UI where we have a TextField, that I push to the financeData class in order to build the URL. Currently, my goal would be, to be able to show just the name of any given object in my response in the UI. I have no idea how to initialize my financeDate and how to use the return from my finaceData class in the UI. (I took some design styles out of the code snippet).

```
class SearchScreenWatchlist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchScreenWatchlistState createState() => _SearchScreenWatchlistState();
}

class _SearchScreenWatchlistState extends State<SearchScreenWatchlist> {
  String searchInput;
  FinanceData financeData = FinanceData(); 
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                searchInput = value;
              },
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                financeData.getSearchData(searchInput);
                setState(() {
                });
              },
              child: Text('Search')),
          Text(('Search Results for: $searchInput')),
          Container(child: Text('**SHOW HERE THE NAME**')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It would be my goal to show in the last container the name on any given object from my response for example RESPONSE.name[1]. Later on I will try to iterate throw all the objects and show a list of all names of the response.

Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing `SearchScreenWatchlist` to the following should display the name of the first `bestMatches` entry after you pressed the Search button (if I didn't miss something).

Make sure to look further into [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) and [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) (And the StatefulWidget lifecycle in general). Also it may not be the most elegant way to initialize FinanceData() and SearchOutput() this way - However, *awesome starter project*!

```
class SearchScreenWatchlist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchScreenWatchlistState createState() => _SearchScreenWatchlistState();
}

class _SearchScreenWatchlistState extends State<SearchScreenWatchlist> {
  String searchInput;
  FinanceData financeData;
  SearchOutput searchOutput;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    financeData = FinanceData();
    searchOutput = SearchOutput();
  }

  _handleButtonPress() async {
    final fetchedSearchOutput = await financeData.getSearchData(searchInput);
    setState(() {
      searchOutput = fetchedSearchOutput;
    });
  }

  _buildSearchResult() {
    if(searchOutput.bestMatches != null && searchOutput.bestMatches.isNotEmpty) {
      return Text(searchOutput.bestMatches.first.name);
    }
    else {
      return Text("No data fetched");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  searchInput = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => _handleButtonPress(),
            child: Text('Search'),
          ),
          Text(('Search Results for: $searchInput')),
          Container(
            child: _buildSearchResult(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind words and the real quick response! 

I just tried out this morning the changes you proposed. Unfortunately, I'm running into an exception when trying to build the screen:
'
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SearchScreenWatchlist(dirty, state: _SearchScreenWatchlistState#8fdf4):

The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isEmpty
'
I assume I'm still struggling with how to correctly initialize my values. I will definitely check out the docs on initState and setState this evening, thanks for mentioning it

Comment: Oh, yes `bestMatches` is null initially - I missed that. I fixed my answer to check for null in `_buildSearchResult()`.